# No Material widget found flutter vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, widget, issue-tracking

I am setting an TextField Widget in flutter using VS Code and I am getting this error on TextFormField:

```
No Material widget found.
TextField widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
I/flutter ( 3827): In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's
I/flutter ( 3827): material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget
I/flutter ( 3827): that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that
I/flutter ( 3827): there be a Material widget in the tree above them.
I/flutter ( 3827): To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains
I/flutter ( 3827): Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.
I/flutter ( 3827): The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was:
I/flutter ( 3827):   TextField
I/flutter ( 3827): The ancestors of this widget were:
I/flutter ( 3827):   ...
I/flutter ( 3827):   TextFormField
I/flutter ( 3827):   Column
I/flutter ( 3827):   Padding
I/flutter ( 3827):   Padding
I/flutter ( 3827):   Container
```

And the code of TextFormField is:

```
TextFormField txtEmail(String title, IconData icon) {
        return TextFormField(
          controller: emailController,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: title,
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
              icon: Icon(icon)),
        );
      }
```

And Actually I am calling the txtEmail in this:

```
Container textSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          txtEmail("Email", Icons.email),
          SizedBox(height: 30.0),
          txtPassword("Password", Icons.lock),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a Material Widget as a root Object(for example MaterialApp)

```
void main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: MyApp(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

check out https://flutter.dev/ for tutorials.